# QT5.10.1 no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer" on Window

Tags: qt, qml

I create a Video on QML, import QtMultimedia 5.8 to play the video.It can play well, but when I import some libraries of Qt3D in this QML file, it is error.

```
"error The system cannot find the file specified."
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

It is only happened in **Debug mode OS Window7**
**Release mode in OS window7** is okay. I try it on **Ubuntu with gstreamer** library, it can play well on both Debug & Release.
I gg, some article said that it is because of Media plugin. From mingw53_32/plugins/mediaservice, there are 4 file dsengine.dll/dsengined.dll and qtmedia_audioengine.dll/qtmedia_audioengined.dll.

Is it a bug from QT?

---EDIT------

I my project, I use MediaPlayer with some Scene3D items. It can play well on Release mode but not in Debug mode. The source code is similar like that:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.9
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.0
import Qt3D.Core 2.0 as Qt3D
import Qt3D.Render 2.10 as Qt3DR
import Qt3D.Extras 2.10 as Qt3DE

Item {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
//    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    //    Item {
    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaplayer
        source: "qrc:/example.mp4"
        autoPlay: true
    }

    VideoOutput {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: mediaplayer
    }

    Scene3D{
        id: sence1
    }

    Scene3D{
        id: sence2
    }
    Scene3D{
        id: sence3
    }
    Scene3D{
        id: sence4
    }
}
```

The .pro file:

```
QT += quick  3dcore 3drender 3dinput 3dquick 3dextras 3dquickextras multimedia
CONFIG += c++11
```

---UPDATED-----

I found that it happen when I build with MinGW compiler. When I change to MSVC2015 compiler, it can play well. Maybe there is something different in libraries in these compiler?

Comment: Please, provide a source code explaining the issue.

Comment: It's because MinGW is 32 bit. Switch to x64 if you want to stay on MinGW